# use component in a single page vuejs

Tags: vuejs3

i use vuejs 3.0 inside html page for its binding, it is very usefull. I know almost developer use application, not this way, but i need to understand, there should be a way to load a component (plugin) in the page witouht create project.
may be a command like `Vue.createApp(app).component('b-pagination-nav', BPaginationNav).mount('#app')`

i try with `https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination-nav` t add a pagination for table, but i failed. could someone say me if it is possible?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="app">
   <table>
       <tr v-for="item in row ">
           <td>{{item}}</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>


<script src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
   const app = {
       data() {
           return { rows: ["fr","us","sp","it","pt"] }
       },
       methods: {
       },
   }
   Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use an uncompiled vue project?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say with confidence that I understand what you are asking, but I'm assuming you're trying to use Vue with uncompiled components.

You can link `vue.global.js` using the CDN. `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>`. You can also link it locally, but you're likely getting errors locally because your path includes the `node_modules` folder which is likely not being served with the rest of your assets, so you can copy the vue library to your `public` or `dist` directory (or whatever you are using to serve)

You also have an issue here `<tr v-for="item in row">`, that should be `rows` not `row`

#### Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="app">
   <table>
       <tr v-for="item in rows">
           <td>{{item}}</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script>
   const app = {
       data() {
           return { rows: ["fr","us","sp","it","pt"] }
       },
       methods: {
       },
   }
   Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you Daniel, to publish code with  CDN we have good based for finding solution.
you put some words on my need, start of the solution : use component without webpack .   

so i search internet and found this explanation (code and git link) , could it answer my need? can someone adapt explanation with my request, i don't have enought vuejs experience to do that. 
https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/goodbye-webpack-building-vue-applications-without-webpack/